# File Expiration (File Server) - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-server

I need help. Users are receiving an email originated by File Server, informing them that the files will expire in X days, but there is no such configuration on the file server. Can anyone suggest what could have happened?

Can this configuration be done at any time and was it garbage? Where can I look?

This had never happened before.  These emails were only sent on the 20th of May. I'm afraid to give up and the files really expire, however, I don't know where to look anymore

[Email received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ynk.png)

[Configuration of file server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twXtI.jpg)

Comment: Please check the emails headers to be *sure* they are coming from the fileserver you shown above.